# Storing For Loop values after simulation

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, lambda, simulation

I'm brand new to R and trying to implement a simple model (which I will extend later) that deals with corporate bond defaults.

For starters, I'm using only two clients.

Parameters:
- two clients (which I name "A" and "B")
- a cash flow of $10,000 will be received from each client if they do not default within 10 years
- pulling together concepts using standard normal random variables, dependent uniform random variables and Gaussian copulas
- run some number of simulations
- store the sum of Client A cash flow plus Client B cash flow and store in a vector named "result"
- finally, take the average of the result vector

```
My code is:

# define variables
nSim <- 5           # of simulations
rho <- 0.3          # rho
lambda <- 0.01      # default intensity
T <- 10             # time to default

for (i in 1:nSim){

# Step 1: generate 2 independent standard normal random variables
z1 <- rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=1)
z2 <- rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=1)

# Step 2: map the normals into correlated normals
#         by Cholesky composition of the correlation matrix
# w1 = z1
# w2 = rho(z1)+sqrt(1-(rho^2))*z2

w1 <- z1
w2 <- rho*z1 - sqrt(1-(rho^2))*z2

# Step 3: using the correlated normals, generate two dependent uniform variables
u <- runif(1, min=0, max=1)
v <- runif(1, min=0, max=1)

# Step 4: using the dependent uniforms, generate two dependent exponentials

tau.A <- (-1/lambda)*log(u)
tau.B <- (-1/lambda)*log(v)

payout.A <- if (tau.A > 10) {10000} else {0}
payout.B <- if (tau.B > 10) {10000} else {0}

result[i] = (payout.A[i] + payout.B[i])
}

# calculate expected value of portfolio
mean(result)
```

When I run this code, I'm getting an error of "NA" and can't figure out why (again, I'm brand new to R).  I don't think each of the simulation values is being stored in the results vector, but don't know how to diagnose the problem.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

--Sarah

Answer (score 1):

Everything works until the `results[i] <- (payout.A[i] + payout.B[i])` line.  The problem is you never set `results`.

Before your `for` loop, add the line:

```
results <- vector('numeric', length = nSim)
```

This will create a vector of 0s with a length of `nSim`.  In R is is best to preallocate the space instead of dynamically growing a vector using `c()`.

Answer (score 1):

No the problem is the presence of the `[i]` assignments in the `results[i] <- (payout.A[i] + payout.B[i])` line.
The `[i]` assignment is okay for the results parameter but not the two payout parameters because each of these are being generated in each loop. So simply remove them to form the line:

```
results[i] <- (payout.A + payout.B)
```

will solve your issue. If you wish to keep each payout in its own vector then you need to assign it as such, but it seems that you don't.

Comment: Put 4 spaces in front of your code to format it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!